# Помогите составить код с операторами switch,break,goto

Tags: c++, switch

Сейчас делаю задачу из интернета,основная цель используя оператор `switch`, составить программу для получения таблицы значений функции `У` для целочисленных значений аргумента `Х` из интервала(-10;15).

Когда `Х(7,9,11)`, `У=sqrt(fabs(x-10))`

Когда `Х(6,8,10,12)`,  `У=pow(tan(x/5),2)`

Когда `Х(-2,5)`, `У=2*sin(x/p)`

Во всех остальных случаях `У=exp(x+2)`

Я бы хотел что бы в ответ выводились все варианты `X` и `У` + сократить код. Как это можно сделать?
P.S. За ошибки сильно не пинайте,пожалуйста. 2 неделю обучаюсь.

```
    #include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x,y,p;
    switch(-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
    {
    case 7:   
    cout <<"X=7,y=sqrt(fabs(x-10))";
    case 11:
    cout <<"X=11,y=sqrt(fabs(x-10))";
    case 9:
    cout <<"X=9,y=sqrt(fabs(x-10))";
    case 6:
    cout <<"X=6,y=pow(tan(x/5),2)";
    case 8:
    cout <<"X=8,y=pow(tan(x/5),2)";
    case 10:
    cout <<"X=10,y=pow(tan(x/5),2)";
    case 12:
    cout <<"X=12,y=pow(tan(x/5),2)";
    case -2:
    cout <<"X=-2,y=2*sin(x/p)";
    case 5:
    cout <<"X=5,y=2*sin(x/p)";
    default:
    cout <<"X=!(-10...15),y=exp(x+2)";
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: `switch(-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)` - что это ? Так можно ? Первый раз вижу. [https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k0t5wee3.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k0t5wee3.aspx)

Comment: Что такое ваше `p`?

Comment: Ну,вероятно так можно,в ответ выводит default. P=3.14. Совсем про него забыл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас непонятно, что такое `p`, далее, `x` действительно должен быть целым, но `y` - `double`. Если позарез нужен `switch` - то, например, [так](https://ideone.com/Bnb1ps) (еще раз обратите внимание на `p`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    double p = 1.0; // ???;  <-- Тут надо определить ваше p
                    // Чтоб компилировалось, я дал ему значение 1
    cout << "  x       y\n-----------------\n";
    for(int x = -10; x <= 15; ++x)
    {
        double y;
        switch(x)
        {
        case  7:
        case  9:
        case 11: y = sqrt(fabs(x-10)); break;
        case  6:
        case  8:
        case 10:
        case 12: y = tan(x/5.0); y *= y; break;
        case -2:
        case  5: y = 2*sin(x/p); break;
        default: y = exp(x+2);
        }
        cout << setw(3) << x << "  " << setprecision(7) << setw(12) << y << endl;
    }
}
```

P.S. Для `goto` места не нашел, разве что цикл через него вручную делать...

Comment: Огромное спасибо,все работает. Только пришлось добавить getch() ,что бы не закрывалось моментально.
Я выберу Ваш вопрос как решение проблемы,только ответьте- как понимать смысл последней строки?
Отступить 3 символа,вывести Х->Дальше ???->Опять ???->Отступить 12 символов перед ответом->окончить строку

Comment: И еще,программа не может "Чудить"?   8      1171.866 Просто некоторые ответы очень большие выходят...
   8      1171.866                       

  9             1                                

 10      4.774399
                                       
 11             1

 12     0.8390822

 13       3269017

 14       8886111
 
15  2.415495e+007`
к сожалению нормально поставить в столбик не получается

Comment: https://ibb.co/mSvPHU

Comment: Ну, числа просчитайте сами руками на калькуляторе, если хотите. Последняя строка: `setw()` - это какая ширина (число знакомест) для следующего выводимого значения (не отступ! вся ширина), `setprecision` - точность (сколько знаков после запятой).

Comment: Ну вот берем 15. У вас для него - exp(x+2), т.е. exp(17). Калькулятор говорит - 24154952,7535753. Вроде как похоже, нет? :)

Answer (score 3):

```
  #include<math.h>
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<iostream>

  using namespace std;

  void main()
  {
     int x,y;
     cin>>x;
     switch(x)
     {
       case 7:
       case 9:
       case 11:
         y=sqrt(fabs(x-10));
         cout<<"x= "<<x<<"y=sqrt(fabs("<<x<<"-10))="<<y;
         break;
       case 6:
       case 8:
       case 10:
       case 12:
          y=pow(tan(x/5),2)
          cout<<"x= "<<x<<"y=pow(tan("<<x<<"/5),2)="<<y;
          break;
       case -2:
       case 5:
          y=2*sin(x/p);cout<<y;
          break;
       default:
         y=exp(x+2);cout<<y;
         break;
     }
     getchar();
  }
```